# Getting the check changed event for a dynamically created Radio Group within a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

We are working on a project where there is a questionnaire with dynamically created radio groups with radio buttons.At the bottom of the listview we have placed a button and we need the selected values from the radio buttons on clicking the button.**The issue is how to get the selected Radio button values.Also i wanted to know in which class i can get the values in the main activity or in the Base Adapter class?**

We have done the following:

The main activity:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(m=0;m<question_list_array.size();m++)
                {


                        View view= question_list.getChildAt(m);
                        RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.single_radiogroup);
                        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                                for(int n=0;n<group.getChildCount();n++)
                                {
                                    RadioButton rb= (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(n);
                                    if (rb.getId() == checkedId) {
                                        String result= rb.getText()+"";
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        // do something with text
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }


        });
```

But i am getting NPE at the following line:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.single_radiogroup);
```

The adapter class:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String question_type = question_list_array.get(position).getQuestion_type();
        option_list = question_list_array.get(position).option_list;
        number_of_options = option_list.size();



            v_single=convertView;
            if (v_single == null) {
                v_single = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_layout, null);
                sh = new SingleHolder();
                sh.single_question_name = (TextView) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_question_name);
                sh.single_radiogroup = (RadioGroup) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_radiogroup);
                v_single.setTag(sh);

            }
            else
            {
                sh = (SingleHolder) v_single.getTag();
            }
            sh.single_radiogroup.clearCheck();
            sh.single_radiogroup.removeAllViews();
            sh.single_question_name.setText(question_list_array.get(position).getQuestion_name());
            for (int j = 0; j < number_of_options; j++)
            {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
                rb.setText(option_list.get(j).getOption_name());
                sh.single_radiogroup.addView(rb);
            }
       v_final=v_single;


        return v_final;
    }
```

We dont have any issues with the Adapter as such.Please reply at the earliest.

Comment: Set `setOnCheckedChangeListener ` in `getView ` method for RadioGroup

Comment: But i want to get the values from the click event of the button which is in the main activity.

Comment: ok for getting checked value use ArrayList or HashMap in getView method for storing and access it on button click event

Comment: But how do i get the ArrayList or HashMap stored in the Adapter class into my Activity?